# Translate draco compressed glb to svf using autodesk translate api

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I tried translating a draco compressed glb to svf format to load it in forge viewer. But I'm getting the following error in response when using autodesk translate api.

{"messages":[{"type":"error","message":"Extractor error code -1073741819","code":"TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"}],"outputType":"svf"}]}

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately GLBs *with Draco compression* are not supported by the Forge Model Derivative service. Consider pre-processing the files into standard GLBs using tools like https://www.npmjs.com/package/gltf-pipeline.